# Python : How to release `enter` key in python

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`.When i run `test.py` then shows a form with 2 `TextInput`. 
I am moving from one TextInput to another TextInput using `Enter` key.When  i do not fill both `TextInput` and move using enter key.After that i `focused` `ok` button and i press `Enter` key then i call `insert` function and check it is blank or not.It it's blank then i set `focus` on `Name` TextInput using this function.

```
def insert(self):
    if self.name.text == "":
        self.name.focus = True
```

After focus `name` TextInput it calls `root.on_enter_text_input()` by default.So it move on next `TextInput`.But i want focus on `name` TextInput.
Can someone tell me how to stop `root.on_enter_text_input()` function at this time when i call `insert` function?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 300)


class User(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    class1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    #cls = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.name_focus, 1)

    def name_focus(self, *args):
        self.name.focus = True

    def on_enter_text_input(self):
        self.class1.focus = True

    def on_enter_text_input1(self):
        self.postUser.focus = True
        self.postUser.background_color = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus) and keycode == 40:  # 40 - Enter key pressed
            self.postUser.focus = False
            self.postUser.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]
            self.insert()


    def insert(self):
        if self.name.text == "":
            self.name.focus = True

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

User:
    name: name
    class1:class1
    postUser : postUser
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 20, 20
            spacing: 10, 10

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id:name
                multiline: False
                text_size: self.size
                on_text_validate: root.on_enter_text_input()
            Label:
                text: "Class"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id:class1
                multiline: False
                text_size: self.size
                on_text_validate: root.on_enter_text_input1()

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 0, 0
            spacing: 5, 0
            size_hint: .5, .35
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 0}

            Button:
                id:postUser
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Ok"
                focus: False
                on_release:
                    root.insert()
                    root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add `return True` indicating that we have consumed the Enter key pressed and don’t want it to propagate any further. Please refer to the snippets below.

## Snippets

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus) and keycode == 40:  # 40 - Enter key pressed
        self.postUser.focus = False
        self.postUser.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]
        self.insert()
        return True
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like below

```
class User(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    class1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    #cls = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initial_focusing = False
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.name_focus, 1)

    def name_focus(self, *args):
        self.name.focus = True

    def on_enter_text_input(self):
        if self.initial_focusing:
           self.initial_focusing = False
        else:
           self.class1.focus = True

    def on_enter_text_input1(self):
        self.postUser.focus = True
        self.postUser.background_color = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus) and keycode == 40:  # 40 - Enter key pressed
            self.postUser.focus = False
            self.postUser.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]
            self.insert()


    def insert(self):
        if self.name.text == "":
            self.initial_focusing = True
            self.name.focus = True
```